# Android Studio + MySQL Workbench: can't connect to database using JDBC

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm fairly new at developing apps. I've began a tutorial on how to connect an app to a database using JDBC driver. I'm using Android Studio and MySQL Workbench.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbtest", "root", "123");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * from tblHockeyPlayers";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                double number = rs.getDouble("number");
                hockeyPlayersMap.put(name, number);
            }

            msg = "Process successful.";

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException connError) {
            msg = "An exception was thrown for JDBC";
            connError.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            msg = "A class not found exception was thrown";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null){
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                if (conn != null){
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The line `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DbStrings.USERNAME, DbStrings.PASSWORD);` always triggers this error (catches an `SQLException`):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception: java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 3306) from /:: (port 35618): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 3306) from /:: (port 35618): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 3306) from /:: (port 35618): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:143)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1805)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
at com.sportsknowledge.mysqlexampleproject.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:69)
at com.sportsknowledge.mysqlexampleproject.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:50)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

I have tried to use XAMMP and EasyPHP and read all sort of things that didn't work out. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: So you're connecting an Android device to a computer with the database? If yes, I doubt the server is on the phone itself. Find the computers internal IP

Comment: I'm developing an app on my computer using Android Studio. When I build it to test it out, I get the error. The server (MYSQL Workbench) is on my computer, that's why I put localhost or 127.0.01.

Comment: So this is a desktop app? Then **why did you tag android??**

Comment: When the code executes, it's running on the Android device. For the device, the DB is not on `localhost`, as `localhost` is the device itself! You have to provide the actual IP of your machine so that the phone can find it.

Comment: No it's an android phone app. I'm testing it out on a Nexus 5 Android Emulator. When I build the app from Android Studio, the emulator starts and I can test the app.

Comment: I have tried putting the actual IP of my machine and the same error popped out. The only difference is that it took more time.

Comment: If you're using an **android emulator**, it is an Android app.